# Flask Babel: adding pycountry external locale

Tags: flask, flask-babel

I am trying to add an external locale directory from the [`pycountry`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry) package.

Before initializing Flask Babel, I do the following:

```
import pycountry
app.config['BABEL_TRANSLATION_DIRECTORIES'] = 'translations;' + pycountry.LOCALES_DIR
```

But alas, this does not seem to be enough. For example, `gettext('Germany')` will not find the translation.

I think the problem might be how translations are structured in `pycountry`.

```
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pycountry/locales/pt/LC_MESSAGES$ ls
iso15924.mo   iso3166-3.mo  iso4217.mo   iso639-3.mo
iso3166-1.mo  iso3166.mo    iso639_3.mo
```

Do I need to specify I want, e.g., the `iso3166` file? Please see the following reference.

- Reference: [pycountry locale documentation section](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry)

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to load pycountry locale with `flask babel`.

To do that, I look into [flask-babel get_translations()](https://github.com/python-babel/flask-babel/blob/master/flask_babel/__init__.py) about how they load translations.

Anyway, I have something working putting this somewhere in your app.

```
def hack_country_gettext(string):
    translations = support.Translations()
    catalog = translations.load(pycountry.LOCALES_DIR, [get_locale()], 'iso3166')
    translations.merge(catalog)
    return translations.ugettext(string)
```

and instead of `_('Germany')` use the hack function `hack_country_gettext('Germany')`